# To Retrieve a single row using 3 tables

Tags: mysql, case

I have 3 tables namely person, person2, person3. Each of the table contains two fields name and phno.
If I give a particular phno the query have to display the presence of that number in each table

I tried something like this:

```
select a.name as Name, a.phno,
case when a.phno then 'Y' else 'N' end as Phone_Number1,
case when b.phno then 'Y' else 'N' end as Phone_Number2,
case when c.phno then 'Y' else 'N' end as Phone_Number3
from person as a, person2 as b, person3 as c
where a.phno = '123456' and b.phno = '123456' and c.phno = '123456';
```

This query works only if all the table contains value for that particular phno..

I need out put like

```
phno      Phone_Number1  Phone_Number2  Phone_Number3
123456        Y               Y              Y
```

if it present in all the tables

```
phno      Phone_Number1  Phone_Number2  Phone_Number3
123456        N              Y                Y
```

if it is not present , then 'N' should be dispayed in that particular table..

Answer (score 0):

I'd try adding a comparison to each case/when:

```
select a.name as Name, a.phno,
case when a.phno = '123456' then 'Y' else 'N'               end as Phone_Number1,
case when b.phno = '123456' then 'Y' else 'N' end as Phone_Number2,
case when c.phno = '123456' then 'Y' else 'N' end as Phone_Number3
from person as a, person2 as b, person3 as c
where a.phno = '123456' or b.phno = '123456' or c.phno = '123456';
```

Comment: This won't work. If the row is missing from any table, the join doesn't return anything, because it's a cross-product.

Comment: try it without the `where`?

Comment: Now you'll get a zillion rows, because you're generating a cross-product of all 3 entire tables.

Comment: Oh OK I misread... So only one needs to contain the number? If so, can you try my last edit?

Comment: @jerdiggity your code will retrieve all the values from all the tables since you are using or condition...
and  to all it can be achieved only with case statements without using union and all...I am trying to figure it out...

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MAX(Phone_Number1) Phone_Number1, MAX(Phone_Number2) Phone_Number2, MAX(Phone_Number3) Phone_Number3
FROM (SELECT "Y" Phone_Number1, "N" Phone_Number2, "N" Phone_Number3
      FROM person
      WHERE phno = '123456'
      UNION
      SELECT "N" Phone_Number1, "Y" Phone_Number2, "N" Phone_Number3
      FROM person2
      WHERE phno = '123456'
      UNION
      SELECT "N" Phone_Number1, "N" Phone_Number2, "Y" Phone_Number3
      FROM person3
      WHERE phno = '123456'
      UNION
      SELECT "N", "N", "N" -- In case they're not in any table
     ) u
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT IFNULL(IFNULL(a.name, b.name), c.name) AS Name, IFNULL(IFNULL(a.phno,b.phno),c.phno) AS phone, 
   CASE WHEN a.phno IS NULL THEN 'N' ELSE 'Y' END AS Phone_Number1,
   CASE WHEN b.phno IS NULL THEN 'N' ELSE 'Y' END AS Phone_Number2,
   CASE WHEN c.phno IS NULL THEN 'N' ELSE 'Y' END AS Phone_Number3
  FROM `person` AS a 
  RIGHT OUTER JOIN person2 AS b ON a.phno = b.phno
  RIGHT OUTER JOIN person3 AS c ON a.phno = c.phno
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT IFNULL(IFNULL(a.name, b.name), c.name) AS Name, IFNULL(IFNULL(a.phno, b.phno), c.phno) AS phone, 
   CASE WHEN a.phno IS NULL THEN 'N' ELSE 'Y' END AS Phone_Number1,
   CASE WHEN b.phno IS NULL THEN 'N' ELSE 'Y' END AS Phone_Number2,
   CASE WHEN c.phno IS NULL THEN 'N' ELSE 'Y' END AS Phone_Number3
  FROM `person` AS a 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN person2 AS b ON a.phno = b.phno
  LEFT OUTER JOIN person3 AS c ON a.phno = c.phno
) k
WHERE k.phone = '123456'
GROUP BY k.phone
```

or if you are joining it by name or something else put a.name = b.name or a.id = b.id or a.something = b.something
if you want to see all numbers just remove where

Answer (score 0):

Nice question, Thanks for posting.

Please try the following select query:

```
select a.name as Name, a.phno,
case when a.phno = '123456' then 'Y' else 'N' end as Phone_Number1,
case when b.phno = '123456' then 'Y' else 'N' end as Phone_Number2,
case when c.phno = '123456' then 'Y' else 'N' end as Phone_Number3
from person as a, person2 as b, person3 as c
```

Or

```
select a.name as Name, a.phno,
case a.phno when  '123456' then 'Y' else 'N' end as Phone_Number1,
case b.phno when  '123456' then 'Y' else 'N' end as Phone_Number2,
case c.phno when  '123456' then 'Y' else 'N' end as Phone_Number3
from person as a, person2 as b, person3 as c
```